# How to get M:1 relation in Yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to get related model however i cannot seem to find correct documention. In yii 1.x i can do `$jobsprocess->category0`, but yii 2.x tell me to do `$jobsprocess->getCategory()`. This does not return a model but an `ActiveQuery`. How can I return a model object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query use `$model = YourModel::find()->with(['category])->all()`.

All relations using the getRelation() functions can be access with the `with()` function, but without the `get` and lowercase first letter.

You can then access the relational data with `$model->category`.